# AJAX Event Handlers - beforeSend, fail and done

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to attach an "on begin" handler to an AJAX call but I am getting

*TypeError: request.beforeSend is not a function*

As far as what I read on the [JQuery docs site](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), the following should work, but alas, something is amuck. Thanks for looking

**(Using JQuery 1.10.2)**

```
  //Init the AJAX request and send
            var request = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                traditional: true,
                dataType: "html",
                url: "/NewClubOpeningTool/DeleteSelectedEmails/",
                data: { delete : checkedValues,clubId:"@Model.NewClub_Id" },
                cache: true
            });

            request.beforeSend(function() {

                $("#loading-area").show();

            });


            request.done(function (payload) {

            $("#loading-area").hide();
                //Do stuff ...

            });


            request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {

                 $("#loading-area").hide();
                //Do stuff...
            });
```

Comment: The quoted error message seems to indicate that `beforesend` was used as opposed to `beforeSend`. Javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: @TravisJ Thanks for pointing that out however that was just a typo. I fixed it quickly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var request = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                traditional: true,
                dataType: "html",
                url: "/NewClubOpeningTool/DeleteSelectedEmails/",
                data: { delete : checkedValues,clubId:"@Model.NewClub_Id" },
                cache: true,
                beforeSend : function() {
                              $("#loading-area").show()
                             }
                });
```

Comment: You will need to do the same with the done and fail functions also or they will throw the same error as beforeSend.

Comment: That worked. Not sure why beforeSend cannot be treated like fail and done, though

Comment: @Slinky `beforeSend (Local Event) This event, which is triggered before an Ajax request is started`  https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/ `The jqXHR Object These methods take one or more function arguments that are called when the $.ajax() request terminates.` `jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {});` https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR